# Возможно ли сделать полиморфную связь в Yii2?

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii2

Есть 4 таблицы - упрощенно можно представить так (БД PostgresSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS(
  ID   INT              NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
  TYPE_PRODUCT INT      NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE FOODS (
  ID   INT              NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
  STATUS VARCHAR (50)
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CLOTHES (
  ID   INT              NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
  STATUS VARCHAR (50)
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CLEANERS (
  ID   INT              NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
  STATUS VARCHAR (50)
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Смысл такой - товар поступает на склад и регистрируется в первой таблице. После приемки и регистрации манагер отправляет товар в зависимости от типа в отделы - Продукты питания, Одежда, Чистящие средства. Запись о товаре создается в соответствующей таблице. То есть копируется из первой таблицы. Здесь упрощенно представил, на самом деле полей в таблицах очень много и в каждом отделе разные поля. Поэтому видимо была сделана такая структура. Но есть поле статус в этих таблицах. Возможно ли сделать так чтобы при выводе списка товаров из первой главной таблицы можно было выводить вычисляемое поле STATUS из 2, 3, 4 таблиц.

Я думаю добавить в главную таблицу поле EXTERNAL_ID (куда записывать id из таблицы куда была скопирована запись) и с помощью полиморфной связи (в зависимости от TYPE_PRODUCT) вытаскивать это поле Статус.

Как это можно сделать в Yii2? На Laravel это сделать просто - там встроенные средства есть. Нужно только вытаскивать это поле при выводе списка(сортировке) - ограничения не требуются. Из главной таблицы изменять это поле не будут

Я принимаю что это все можно было сложить в одну таблицу или сделать поле статус в главную таблицу. Но там проблема в правах доступа. Менеджеры в отделах не могут ни смотреть ни редактировать главную таблицу. Это все используется уже очень долго и никто не позволит сильно менять структуру. Можно только добавить поле в главную таблицу

Comment: Нелогично. По сути тут только одна сущность - продукт. А то, что распихивается в три разных таблицы в зависимости от типа - это всего лишь хоть и достаточно мощный по наполнению, но атрибут этой сущности. Поскольку статус - это атрибут продукта, а не суб-атрибут его атрибута, то хрен ли это поле делает в частных таблицах? поубирать оттуда, и создать его в таблице PRODUCTS.

Comment: Там в правах доступа к таблицам проблема.

Comment: Более того, я вообще не понимаю, зачем тут три таблицы. Одна таблица, пусть и разреженная. была бы куда как логичнее. А для разделения - создать соответствующие представления, с нужными доступами, а то ещё и партиционировать. Если нужна сложная система прав, то по-любому надо начинать с полного отсечения от прямого доступа к данным.

Comment: Сейчас уже никто не позволит сильно изменить структуру - нужно малой кровью отделаться. У менеджеров отделов есть доступ только в свою таблицу. Так что писать в главную им нельзя. Права не дадут поменять. Главный менеджер имеет доступ во все таблицы

Comment: Всё равно добавить поле в основную таблицу. Только обновлять его значение из триггеров на частных таблицах. Или каждый раз джойнить частные таблицы и брать оттуда статусы.

Comment: *У менеджеров отделов есть доступ только в свою таблицу. Так что писать в главную им нельзя.* Не смешно. Хранимка от рута с SECURITY DEFINER, и всё.

Answer (score 0):

вначале нужно создать таблицу/поле для соотношения TYPE_PRODUCT с именем таблицы, потом установить по какому полю будет идентифицироваться продукт - id или name.

```php
class ProductModel extends ActiveRecord
{
    protected $productTables = [
        1 => 'FOODS',
        2 => 'CLOTHES',
        ...
    ];

    public function getTypeInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne($this->productTables[$this->type_product], ['id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```